# ROR + Ruby Date Format For 2 days before from Today Date

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In ruby,

```
@today_date = Time.now.utc.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

If today date is :: 2011-07-20

But Now I want date `before 2 days :: 2011-07-17` by using Ruby Code. Please suggest something.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
# 1:
(Time.now - 2.days).utc.strftime....
# 2:
2.days.ago.utc.strftime...
```

Answer (score 4):

First of all 2011-07-17 is not 2 days before 2011-07-20 but 3..Anyway in Rails:

```
2.days.ago.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

In Ruby:

```
(Time.now-2*24*60*60).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

Hope I helped..